# javascript autocomplete selfmade positioning problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete, position

I have made my own autocomplete feature using javascript and ajax.
It is all working out well, but i have one major problem: the positioning.
I am currently positioning the list like this:

```
function ajaxautocomplete(elm)
{
    lista.innerHTML="";
        var x=getOffset(elm).left;
        var y=getOffset(elm).top;
        lista.style.position="absolute";
        lista.style.left=(x+5)+"px";
        lista.style.top=(y+25)+"px";
...
}
```

Where "lista" is my autocomplete list and "elm" is the current text input.
Now, i have a table with text inputs as cells, and they need to have this auto-complete feature. This positioning works, but if the table is big enough and it needs scrolling, when i scroll down the page and try to autocomplete a cell at the bottom, the positioning doesn't work anymore, and my list appears somewhere on top of the page, maybe out of the screen if i scroll enough.

Any ideea how can i dinamically assign a position to that list even when i'm scrolling the page?
    Thank you!

Edit:
  I forgot to mention, this is my getOffset(elm) function:

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us the DOM of your table, input and lista elements?

Comment: Sure, here is the list: http://pastebin.com/DYcJCkv0

Comment: And here is the table: http://pastebin.com/xgXr3QLL

Answer (score 0):

why not use a jquery plug that is build for this, like [this one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) or some other plug in. Otherwise you have a lot of work to do and it's just not worth it, trying to calculate autocomplete position acording to the screen visible part is big apple..

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, i tried to use that and it's not really what i need. I need to customize it a bit more. Plus, i did most of the work already, all i need to do is figure out this positioning...